# Custom directory for logged in users in ASP.NET Mvc site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, routes, seo, robots.txt

I'm working on a ASP.Net MVC project in which there is no difference in url formats between logged in user and normal user, they all  browse pages like these urls:

```
 www.example.com/home/contents (anyone)
 www.example.com/home/about (anyone)
 www.example.com/order/list (page for logged in user)
 www.example.com/help/contact (page for logged in user)
 www.example.com/buy-now (custom url for route order/buy action)
```

I want to move user logged in pages to different folder so that search providers will not index these pages. Pages that are not log-in needed should remain with same url. So result should be

```
 www.example.com/home/contents (anyone)
 www.example.com/home/about (anyone)
 www.example.com/user/order/list (page for logged in user)
 www.example.com/user/help/contact (page for logged in user)
 www.example.com/user/buy-now (custom url for route order/buy action)
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you use Areas?

Comment: If i use Areas, should i move controller and view files into that area folders? I started without using Areas, so all view files are under Views folder and Controller classes in Controller folder. I want to achieve this with minimum changes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use Area's.
Create a User Area and move all your Order and Help etc controller that are for logged in user into that area.

If you do not want to move this to an user area. You can do route config as well. Something similar to -

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "User",
                url: "user/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```